# What's difference between "to be concerned with", "to be concerned about" and "to be concerned for"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I found phrases to be concerned with and to be concerned about in my textbook, and it says that there *is* some difference. But I don't understand it for now so I would be thankful if anyone explains that.

Answer (score 1):

**Concerned with**:
Lexico's first definition of *[concern](https://www.lexico.com/definition/concern)* (verb) is

```
Relate to; be about
```

*the book is concerned with the writer's childhood*
*the book concerns the writer's childhood*

These both mean *the book is **about** the writer's childhood*.

**Concerned about**:
Lexico's definition of [concerned](https://www.lexico.com/definition/concerned) (adjective) is

```
Worried, troubled, or anxious
```

*I was dreadfully concerned about his health*
*Were you concerned for me?*

By the way, when you are at Lexico, clicking on "More example sentences" brings up a list with many examples of a word's usage.